# Node Js use of fast-csv for reading csv (How to use Database queries inside ondata)

Tags: node.js

How to Use inner code inside `.on("data")` NodeJs as it runs fast?

This is my code below.

```
csv.fromPath(newpath).on("data", function(data){
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET phone = ?, name = ?,first_name = ?,last_name = ? ",[phone,full_name,first_name,last_name], function(err,rows,fields) {
        if(err){
            throw new Error(err);
            connection.release();
        }
    var user_two = rows.insertId;

connection.query("INSERT INTO conversation (user_one,user_two,ip,time) VALUES(?, ?, ?,?)",['1',user_two,"",date_time], function(err,rows,fields) {

            if(err) {
                throw new Error(err);
                connection.release();
            }

                        var response = handleResults(rows,err);

                        var c_id_fk = rows.insertId;

                        var  message = "Activity Log: ";

                        connection.query("INSERT INTO conversation_reply (reply,user_id_fk,ip,time,c_id_fk) VALUES(?, ?, ?,?,?)",[message,'1',"",date_time,c_id_fk], function(err,rows,fields) {
                            if(err){
                                throw new Error(err);
                                connection.release();
                            }
                        });
                    }); //end of insert 
                });
});
```

How to use Database queries inside `ondata`?

Thanks for help and any advice.

Comment: Only one query executes (Other query just simply skips)